# mount LVM volume

Tags: lvm, openstack-cinder

I have installed openstack cinder module. Everything works great.
but i want to mount a volume in order to see its contents.

I typed lvscan command on cinder storage computer. I can see my volume list.

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cinder-volumes/volume-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX' [1.00 GiB] inherit
```

but when i type

```
mount /dev/cinder-volumes/volume-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX /mnt
```

i get this error message

```
   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/cinder--volumes-volume--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Is it because volume is already mounted by openstack instance ?
What should i do for mounting or reading/writing data in this volume ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the question/look for answer in Serverfault.

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: stackoverflow are mean for programming. http://serverfault.com/ are specific for system/server config question.